# Python - Ordered Headers HTTP Requests

Tags: python

I am currently using python 2.7 requests library and there is no support for ordered headers. I can put ordered data for post and get (like an ordered dictionary) but there is simply no support for headers. Not even in python 3

I know HTTP protocol RFC, indicates that order of headers is insignificant, but the problem is that the 3rd party service I am implementing with doesn't work unless the headers are in order. I know this because I have implemented ordered headers requests in other languages and it works (like java) and yes I am 100% certain of that, because I inspected on burp, and wireshark to make sure that this is the only difference between the requests. But I already have 5,000+ lines in python so migrating there is such a painful decision because of such a problem.

The only solution I have thought is to implement http protocol on top of TCP myself, but this is not a smart solution. I can't have the same quality of code as available solutions and it is a possible point of failure for my code.

See a simplified code example I have below:

```
data=(("param1","something"),
("param2","something_else"))

headers={'id': 'some_random_number',
'version':'some_random_number' ,
'signature':'some_random_number' ,
                    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ,
                    'charset':'utf-8' ,
                    'Content-Length':str(len(urllib.urlencode(data))) ,
                    'name':'random' ,
                    'User-Agent':'Firefox' ,
                    'Connection':'Keep-Alive' ,
                    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip'}

requests.post("myservice.com",headers=headers, data=data)
```

The order of the request headers is send like that (not actual order, just an example to get my point across)

```
'version':'some_random_number' 
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip'
'id': 'some_random_number'
'User-Agent':'Firefox' 
'signature':'some_random_number' 
'Connection':'Keep-Alive' 
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
'charset':'utf-8'
'name':'random'
```

Which is a problem for me. I don't know what to do at this point. Any help greatly appreciated. I tried urllib library no support

Comment: Would ordered dict work?

Comment: no, using ordered dict gives .items() exception, for the requests library, because requests library parses the headers using the items() method and there is no such support for ordered dict. It used to work in some very old requests version from what I read on another stackoverflow question.

Comment: Can you pass a custom dict-like object to `requests` that has a custom `.items()` which controls the order of the headers returned? If `requests` keeps that order, you are good to go

Comment: that is a good idea, maybe it will work but to be honest, I don't know how to code that.

Comment: A very basic approach to try the concept would be a blank class that takes a tuple of key-value tuples as it's only member and that has a `.items()` method which `return iter(self.header_tuple)`. `requests` calls that method and gets an iterator of `("version", "some_random_number"), ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"), ...` just like it would from a dict.
A more advanced version should involve a topological sorting of the keys so you can express things like "Accept-Encoding should always come before charset and charset should always come before signature"

Comment: Is using Python 3.6 an option?  All dictionaries are ordered in that version of Python.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Is that really true that all dicts are ordered in Python 3.6?

Comment: @SvenMarnach had no idea about that, I will give it a try. I am using 2.7 at the moment, I will check compatibility and update

Comment: @Tobias It is not part of the language specification of Python 3.6, but the CPython implmentation (the one most people are using) implements it that way.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I have heard that **kwargs now come in an OrderedDict but not this. I'll look it up. Thank you for the information!

Comment: @Tobias The order of `kwargs` and class attributes are now guaranteed by the language specification, while the oder of dictionaries in general isn't.  See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation and the preceding sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment, here is a very, very simple `OrderedHeaders` that `requests` might be happy with:

```
class OrderedHeaders(object):

    def __init__(self, *headers):
        self.headers = headers

    def items(self):
        return iter(self.headers)


oh = OrderedHeaders(('Accept-Charset', 'Foo'), ('Bar', 'Foobar'))

for k, v in oh.items():
    print("%s:%s" % (k, v))
```

Here is a more verbose example that uses [topological sorting](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toposort/1.5) to determine which headers must be given before other headers. It requires a little more code, yet you can clearly state what sorting your headers must have once and use the class just like any other dict afterwards.

```
import sys
import toposort

class OrderedHeaders(dict):
    # The precedence of headers is determined once. In this example, 
    # 'Accept-Encoding' must be sorted behind 'User-Agent'
    # (if defined) and 'version' must be sorted behind both
    # 'Accept-Encoding' and 'Connection' (if defined).
    PRECEDENCE = toposort.toposort_flatten({'Accept-Encoding': {'User-Agent'},
                                            'version': {'Accept-Encoding',
                                                        'Connection'}})

    def items(self):
        s = []
        for k, v in dict.items(self):
            try:
                prec = self.PRECEDENCE.index(k)
            except ValueError:
                # no defined sort for this header, so we put it behind
                # any other sorted header
                prec = sys.maxsize
            s.append((prec, k, v))
        return ((k, v) for prec, k, v in sorted(s))

# Initialize like a dict
headers = OrderedHeaders(name='random', Connection='Keep-Alive')
...
# Setting more values
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
headers['version'] = '0.1'
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Firefox'
...
# Headers come out of '.items()' like they should
for k, v in headers.items():
    print("%s: %s" % (k, v))
```

prints

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Firefox
Accept-Encoding: gzip
version: 0.1
name: random
```

because `Connection` needs to come before `version`, `User-Agent` needs to come before `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept-Encoding` needs to come before `version` and `name` has no sorting and is therefor put last.

You can set values on `OrderedHeaders` in any order you want, sorting is done in `.items()`. However you can be sure that a sound ordering is always possible: If you make a mistake and define a circular dependency (e.g. 'version' > 'User-Agent' > 'version'), you'll get a `toposort.CircularDependencyError` at "compile-time".

Comment: the tests I run, the solution works! I am really glad and happy for your answer. I don't know if any more problems arise. But this is a very simple solution and a life saver.

I will mark as correct after I confirm with all tests.

Comment: The lesson to take home here is to remember that in Python one only cares what an object does, not what an object is. `requests` expects an object that acts like a `dict` on `.items()`, and if you pass an actual `dict` that's what you get. You can however pass anything else, as long as the object behaves.